# Is it possible to add a blank sheet to a google spreadsheet using sheets.spreadsheets v4?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

The current api is https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.sheets/copyTo

This is a workaround because I have to first copy an existing sheet and then clear its content before making any use of it.

Google App Script has InsertSheet and it is missing in sheets v4 api.
Why would Google team decide not to do such a simple one?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was not straight forward.
However the answer is in batchUpdate for Sheet Operations
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/sheet#add_a_sheet